# Passing a javascript variable from one script to another

Tags: javascript, variables

I am a totally new to html and javascript and am attempting to create a simple calculator whose output I subsequently want to graph. To achieve that I seem to need to pass a variable from one script to another, but can not manage to achieve this. 
I have managed to compile some code together that I think I can use to expand the calculations to achieve what I need and I have found a helpful chartjs template to create a simple bar chart. However, when I try to override the static input for the chart with my `sngTotal` variable, for example, the variable does not seem to get recognized in the second script. I attempted to define `sngTotal` as a global variable, but it either did not work properly or I did not define it properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Savings </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/globalize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
</head>

<script language="javascript">

    function btnCalculateTotal_Click() {
        var houses = 0;
        var cars = 0;
        var sngTotal = 0;
        houses = Number(frmSimpleCalculator.txtValue1.value);
        cars = Number(frmSimpleCalculator.txtValue2.value);
        sngTotal = houses + cars
        frmSimpleCalculator.txtTotal.value = sngTotal;
    }
</script>

<body bgcolor="#aaaaaa">

    <table style="background-color:black; color:white; width:800">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>calculator</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<form name="frmSimpleCalculator" action="" method="get">
    <fieldset name="fraSimpleCalculator" style="width:1"><legend>Economic Savings Calculator</legend>
    <table width="300" border="0">
    <tr>    <!-- Value 1 -->
        <td align="left">Houses:</td>
        <td align="right"><input type="text" value="500" name="txtValue1" size="10" maxlength="5" style="text-align:right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    <!-- Value 2 -->
        <td align="left">Cars:</td>
        <td align="right"><input type="text" value="25" name="txtValue2" size="10" maxlength="5" style="text-align:right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    <!-- Horizontal rule -->
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    <!-- Total -->
        <td align="left">Total:</td>
        <td align="right"><input type="text" value="0" name="txtTotal" size="10" maxlength="5" style="text-align:right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    <!-- Calculate Button -->
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate Total" name="btnCalculateTotal" style="width:150" OnClick="btnCalculateTotal_Click();">
        </td>
    </tr>

<script>
    $(function ()  {
        var dataSource = [
            { savings: "", Houses: 500, Cars: 300 },
        ];

        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: "savings",
                type: "bar",
                hoverMode: "allArgumentPoints",
                selectionMode: "allArgumentPoints",
                label: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "fixedPoint",
                    precision: 0
                }
            },
            series: [
                { valueField: "Houses", name: "Houses" },
                { valueField: "Cars", name: "Cars" }
            ],
            title: "Savings potential",
            legend: {
                verticalAlignment: "bottom",
                horizontalAlignment: "center"
            },
            pointClick: function (point) {
                this.select();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="title">
    <h1>savings</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="pane">
        <div class="long-title"><h3></h3></div>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 250px; height: 440px;" style="position:absolute; TOP:200px; LEFT:350px"></div>       
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are you using sngTotal in the second script?

Comment: Also note that you don't seem to be closing your table, form or fieldset tags

Answer (score 1):

To make a global variable there are a couple of options

```
sngTotal = 0;
^ leave out the var
```

or

```
window.sngTotal = 0;
^ add to the window object
```

both methods result in a global variable being declared.

**NOTE:** creating global variables is usually frowned upon because it leads to code that is harder to maintain

- Don't know where variables are declared/initialised
- Variables can be overwritten by other scripts at unexpected times

Comment: both methods are correct. you can also use var if the variable is created in the global context instead of in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You code has a problem.  The part that handles the button clicks runs after the chart has already been rendered.  You're not seeing sngTotal because the user hasn't clicked yet.

I'd suggest you modify btnContinue_Click so that it calls the code to render the chart.  It should do this after the total is computed.

```
function btnCalculateTotal_Click()
{
    var houses = 0;
    var cars = 0;
    var sngTotal = 0;
    houses = Number(frmSimpleCalculator.txtValue1.value);
    cars = Number(frmSimpleCalculator.txtValue2.value);
    sngTotal = houses + cars
    frmSimpleCalculator.txtTotal.value = sngTotal;

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart(etc. etc);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Combining both functions such that the button executes the calculations as well as rendering the graph did the trick. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is likely `sngTotal` is getting overwritten somewhere in your second script. Defining global variables won't help if this is the case. My recommendation is to trace it and see where it is being declared.